# Android Blutooth pairing

Tags: android, bluetooth

Is there an action that is associated with "Paired device in Range". i.e can we listen through a Broadcast receiver for an action that would be triggered whenever an already paired device comes in range.

If there are no actions that directly achieve this, is there a way other than constantly polling by scanning (and see if there are bonded devices that are in range)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No because the Bluetooth radio has to perform a discovery session in order to know who's around.

One possibility would be to register a "device found" broadcast receiver and perform a discovery session at an interval. Each device that is discovered will kick off a broadcast, and your special broadcast receiver can then look at those device properties to determine whether it is a device which we have paired with already or not.

Keep in mind bluetooth discovery is a resource intensive process (transmits at a high duty cycle, high power) and puts a significant drain on the battery if used too often.